# error in number separator function in php

Tags: php, function, undefined

i write a function that separate number and insert , every 3 characters
like convert `123456789` to `123,456,789`

my function work correctly but when i use this get 3 error in browser
my function is this :

```
function sefr($num){
    array($lnn);
    $len=strlen($num);
    $zc=intval($len/3);
    for ($za=0;$za<$len;$za++){
    $lnn[$za]=substr($num,$za,1);
    }
    for ($zb=0;$zb<$len;$zb++){
        if ($zb==$len-(3*$zc) ){
        if ($zb!=0){
            $lnnn=$lnnn.",$lnn[$zb]";   
        }
        else {
            $lnnn=$lnnn.$lnn[$zb];
        }   
        $zc--;
        }
        else {
            $lnnn=$lnnn.$lnn[$zb];
        }
    }
    return ($lnnn);
}
```

and i get this errors :

```
Notice: Undefined variable: lnn in file.php on line 2
Notice: Undefined variable: lnnn in file.php on line 14
Notice: Undefined variable: lnnn in file.php on line 19
```

Comment: Use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: And those are *notices*, which result from not pre-initializing used variables.

Comment: thanks,
i use this : $number = number_format($number);
is it true ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is just example where you are grouping the string then you can use `chunk_split`

```
echo trim(chunk_split($num, 3, ","),","); //123,456,78
```

If not if you are dealing with numbers use `number_format`

```
echo number_format($num, 0); //12,345,678
```

Please note that  `123,456,78` != `12,345,678`

Comment: i use this : $number = number_format($number); is it true? it`s work correctly